# WordのVBAで段落番号を「1から再開」にしたい

Tags: vba

Wordの段落番号には「1から再開」という機能がありますが、VBAではどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

例えば契約書の項の番号は各条に紐づいて１もしくは２から始まると思いますが、「1から再開」をしないと条をまたいで項の番号が連番されてしまいます。

＜＜NG＞＞
第1条
１．甲及び乙は…
２．甲は…

第2条
３．甲は…

＜＜OK＞＞
第1条
１．甲及び乙は…
２．甲は…

第2条
１．甲は…

どなたかWordのVBAでコードをご存じの方はお願いします。

```
Private Sub ms_1から再開_()
    Dim lv_Paragraphs_ As Paragraphs
    Set lv_Paragraphs_ = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    
    Dim lv_Is条跨ぎ_ As Boolean
    Dim lv_Index_ As Long
    For lv_Index_ = 1 To lv_Paragraphs_.Count

        Dim lv_Style_ As String
        lv_Style_ = lv_Paragraphs_.Item(lv_Index_).Range.Style
        
        If lv_Style_ = "条" Then lv_Is条跨ぎ_ = True: GoTo Continue
        
        lv_Paragraphs_.Item(lv_Index_).Range.Style = "項A"
   
        If lv_Is条跨ぎ_ Then
            lv_Paragraphs_.Item(lv_Index_).Range.Select
            
            Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel _
                ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(7), _
                ContinuePreviousList:=False, _
                ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList

            lv_Is条跨ぎ_ = False
        End If
Continue:
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: 現状のvbaコードを提示いただけますでしょうか？

Comment: 掲載いただいたコードはどういう想定の元（ワード文書の状態）でどういう動きをするものでしょうか？こちらの関数を使用したコード例とその文章の前後の状態も併せて提示いただけますでしょうか？

Comment: こちらお客様からの契約書や就業規則などを清書する作業となります。
お客様の文書だとWordのスタイルがすべて標準だったり左インデントが適当だったりするのでそこを自動で直したいのです。

プログラムの動きとしては、まずはファイルの全文を取り込み、第●条と書かれたところを「条」のスタイルに変えます（ここは別の関数でやります）。

その後また全文を読み込み、「項」になり得るところを自動で項のスタイルにするのですが、この時に条をまたいでも項の番号が連番になってしまうので何とかしたいと思ってました。

Comment: ただ、すいません。こちら今朝試したらこのコードでできてました。
何が原因なのかわからなかったのですが、解決しました。

Comment: ご対応いただきありがとうございました。